# Error when installing sql server 2000 on vmware (Windows XP)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, vmware

The installer crashes with instruction to check c:\windows\sqlstp.log for more information, here's what the log contains:

```
Connecting to Server ...

driver={sql server};server=JJOHN-vm;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]General network error. Check your network documentation.

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionRead (WrapperRead()).

driver={sql server};server=JJOHN-vm;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]General network error. Check your network documentation.

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionRead (WrapperRead()).

driver={sql server};server=JJOHN-vm;UID=sa;PWD=;database=master

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]General network error. Check your network documentation.

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionRead (WrapperRead()).

SQL Server configuration failed.


###############################################################################

15:57:07 Process Exit Code: (-1) 
15:57:11 Setup failed to configure the server.   Refer to the server error logs and C:\WINDOWS\sqlstp.log for more information.
15:57:11 Action CleanUpInstall:
15:57:11 C:\DOCUME~1\15876\LOCALS~1\Temp\SqlSetup\Bin\scm.exe  -Silent 1 -Action 4 -Service SQLSERVERAGENT
15:57:12 Process Exit Code: (1060) The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

15:57:12 C:\DOCUME~1\15876\LOCALS~1\Temp\SqlSetup\Bin\scm.exe  -Silent 1 -Action 4 -Service MSSQLSERVER
15:57:12 Process Exit Code: (0) 
15:57:12 StatsGenerate returned: 2
15:57:12 StatsGenerate (0x0,0x1,0xf000000,0x300,1033,303,0x0,0x1,0,0,0
15:57:12 StatsGenerate -1,15876)
15:57:12 Installation Failed.
```

I have tried switching the network between host-only, NAT and bridged, disconnecting the network altogether, and among other things tried increasing the vm RAM TO 1gb as well.

Nothing seems to help. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got back to trying this out after a long break...

As it turns out, this is a problem with the **HOSTNAME** :) !!!

SQL server 2000 will not install on hosts assigned a mixed case or lowercase hostname. I renamed the system and it worked fine.

Microsoft provides a hotfix to correct the issue if you're averse to renaming your comp: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285100/en-us .

Comment: Unbelievable! I don't remember haven't this problem back in the days, and I hate to use all uppercase name.

Answer (score 0):

So from the log we can see that MSSQLSERVER service is indeed installed (and SQLSERVERAGENT is not which is irrelevant). The installer tries to access newly installed server using shared memory protocol and fails. I wonder why this might happen. Network configuration isn't relevant here.

Do you have something that prevents shared memory stuff? Could be an advanced firewall with anti-leak detection.

Did you provide some fancy command line keys to not install some parts of the server or to not start the service once it's installed?

Comment: The image I'm using does have a symantec firewall installed... 

However I'm able to confirm that this is not the source of my problem -- I installed the same firewall on my local system and it causes me no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 will always crash if you try to install it through an RDP session. If you ware still installing it at the console of the VM, it might still be a similar issue.

Comment: I am actually running the VM on my local system, and not through RDP.